# How to programmatically deselect a marker in Google Maps on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

When a user clicks on a marker, info window appears, as well as a map toolbar:

[image: example]

I want to "deselect" this marker from code and thus to hide these widgets. The desired behavior is similar to that when a user clicks elsewhere on a map.

I know about `marker.hideInfoWindow()` method, but it only hides the view, keeping the marker in "selected" state.

Comment: Do you wish to "hide these widgets"  or keep them from appearing at all?

Comment: To hide. Let's say, from `onBackPressed()` method.

Comment: "I want to "deselect" this marker from code" :: is there a particular event on which you wish to "deselect" or just after--lets say-- 2 seconds?

Comment: Arbitrary event.

Comment: An "Arbitrary event"  is a bit broad to cover programmatically.

Comment: When a user presses the back button, I want map to "forget" about this marker and focus on user's location. Let's take `onBackPressed()` as a specific event. :)

Comment: You can use the marker click callback to save the last marker - then when the backspace is pressed, use the saved marker to .setVisible(false).

Comment: But this will make the marker invisible. I want it to be visible all the time.

Comment: I see you want to hide them but still be visible - got it.

Comment: I want to hide info window and map toolbar, but keep the marker itself.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete the marker(s) selected and for example you want to show your current position you should do simply:

```
    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
            mMap.clear();
            getLocationData();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

method clear() will delete markers from Map

Comment: I don't want to delete any markers. They are static on the map, and user may want to click on them to see some details. And I want to remove this selection manually.

Comment: So let me understand. You would avoid to user to see info on marker selection, right?

Comment: I want user to see these widgets, but I want to have control over them. Specifically, I need to hide them when a user clicks the back button.

Comment: Check this page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls

Answer (score 0):

If you want the map toolbar and the myLocation button removed from the mapview based on (in this example) the tapping on a marker you can declare a class `boolean` variable that you can use to toggle the visibility of these objects.

```
boolean toggleMapToolBarVisibility = false;
```

Then you can use the `boolean` variable to show the `MapToolBar` and/or the `MyLocation` button. I add this feature to the `OnMarkerClickListener` event, but this behaviour can be added anywhere eg. `onBackPressed()` (but if you do add it somewhere other than in the `onMapReady` method make certain the `GoogleMap` object is not `null`!).

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            try{
                toggleMapToolBarVisibility = !toggleMapToolBarVisibility;
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(toggleMapToolBarVisibility);
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(toggleMapToolBarVisibility);
            }
            catch (SecurityException sec){
                Log.e(TAG, sec.getMessage());
            }
            return false; // you can return true to change the behavior
        }
    });
}
```

> Return true if the `onMarkerClick` listener has consumed the event
>   (i.e., the default behavior should not occur); false otherwise (i.e.,
>   the default behavior should occur). The default behavior is for the
>   camera to move to the marker and an info window to appear.